# mysql stored procedure skip null parameter

Tags: mysql, stored-procedures, parameters, null, where-clause

I think I read all the articles here but still cannot make my code work 100%. I am a PHP form where the user can do a search based on either of the 4 locations or can skip it entirely and in that case should skip the 'where location' clause and move to the next parameter group. My mysql stored procedure looks like this:

```
CREATE PROCEDURE search( 
  IN inRoomsPerPage INT,
  IN inStartItem INT,
  IN inAddDate INT,
  IN inLocation1 ENUM('T','F'),
  IN inLocation2 ENUM('T','F'),
  IN inLocation3 ENUM('T','F'),
  IN inLocation4 ENUM('T','F')
)
BEGIN
SELECT * 
 FROM useradds as ua
 INNER JOIN household as hh on hh.idx_user_id = ua.idx_user_id
 INNER JOIN house as h on h.idx_user_id = ua.idx_user_id
 WHERE adddate >= (CURDATE() - INTERVAL inAddDate DAY) AND
 ((inLocation1 IS NULL OR downtown = inLocation1) OR 
 (inLocation2 IS NULL OR hwy = inLocation2) OR
 (inLocation3 IS NULL OR dewey = inLocation3) OR
 (inLocation4 IS NULL OR lewes = inLocation4))
 ORDER BY ua.adddate DESC
 LIMIT inStartItem, inRoomsPerPage;
 END$$
```

This works fine whenever I select any single or multiple of the locations but doesn't work if I try to skip it (it should just select everything in the last inAddDate).
If I replace

```
(inLocation1 IS NULL OR downtown = inLocation1)
```

with

```
downtown = COALESCE(NULLIF(inLocation1, ''), downtown))
```

then it selects everything if I bypass the location but if I want to do a search for any 2 or more locations it doesn't return anything. I am sure there's gotta be nice way to get over this as I have more where parameter groups to add.

Comment: What do you mean by "skip"? Could you please clarify, ideally with input examples and expected results, what it is you want to happen and when.

Comment: sure. so the php/html part searches the adds post in houses for rent in 4 major locations. However the search gives multiple option: rent, smoking habits, and so, all in the same form. In the form most of user input is checkboxes :

Comment: Where the value come from is irrelevant. I'm talking about parameter values and expected behaviour. Be as clear and precise as you can. As it stands your question is vague and ambiguous.

Comment: ok, I just got a 'work around' solution with this.

Comment: ok, I just got a 'work around' solution with this. my checkboxes are setting the parameter location1 to 'T'(true) if is checked and '' if is not set, and so on for the rest of them. The problem was it didn't show anything when they were not set(checked) and they were all passing '' although I was trying to get ALL Locations. Now I made and IF(!isset($_POST['location1'] AND (!isset($_POST['location2']...){$location1=$location2=..='T' ;} and it works

Comment: apparently I have to wait another 4 hours to post my own answer..:)

Answer (score 0):

My php/html part looks like this:

```
<form action='' method='post'  >
    <select name='ckadddate'>
        <option value='1'>last 24 hours</option>
        <option value='3' selected>last 3 days</option>
        <option value='7'>last week</option></select>
in:<input type='checkbox' name='Downtown' >Downtown
     <input type='checkbox' name='Hwy' >HWY 1
      <input type='checkbox' name='Dewey'>Dewey
      <input type='checkbox' name='Lewes'>Lewes
<input name='SubmitSearch' type='submit' value='Search'>
```

The part of the php function that is calling the stored procedure is:

```
if(isset($_POST['SubmitSearch'])){
    $cklocation1 = $cklocation2= $cklocation3= $cklocation4= '';
    if(isset($_POST['Downtown']))$cklocation1 = 'T';
       if(isset($_POST['Hwy']))$cklocation2 = 'T';
       if(isset($_POST['Dewey']))$cklocation3 = 'T';
       if(isset($_POST['Lewes']))$cklocation4 = 'T';
    **if(!isset($_POST['Downtown']) && !isset($_POST['Hwy']) && !isset($_POST['Dewey']) && !isset($_POST['Lewes'])){
        $cklocation1 = $cklocation2= $cklocation3= $cklocation4= 'T';
    }**
$sql = 'CALL search_room(:RoomsPerPage, :StartItem,:Adddate,
:Location1,:Location2,:Location3,:Location4)';
$params = array (':RoomsPerPage' => ADDS_PER_PAGE, ':StartItem' => $start_item, 
':Adddate' => $_POST['ckadddate'],':Location1' => $cklocation1, 
':Location2' => $cklocation2, ':Location3' => $cklocation3, ':Location4' => $cklocation4
    );
```

This seams to work just fine but I am pretty sure it should be a more elegant solution out there.